# django modelviewset Response add Other Information and when i request Post want not call create()

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

MyPostList.py

```
class PostList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Postinfo.objects.all().order_by('-postuid')[:10] 
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer
```

PostListSerializer.py

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Postinfo
    fields = ("content",
              "useruid")
```

models.py

```
class Postinfo(models.Model):
    postuid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='WorryUID', primary_key=True)
    useruid = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='UserUID')
    content = models.TextField(db_column='Content')
    registerdate = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column='RegisterDate', default=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'postinfo'
```

i want response pagenumber
if i request PostList i want response postlist and PageNo 
like this

```
queryset = Postinfo.objects.all().order_by('-postuid')[:10]
{"PostList":queryset,
 "PageNo":1}
```

and i send pageNo = 2

```
queryset = Postinfo.objects.all().order_by('-postuid')[10:20]
{"PostList":queryset,
 "PageNo":2}
```

i have two problem

1. first request(GET) succes PostList but can't add PageNo
2. if i send PageNo it is not request(GET) this is POST so call create()
   i want return PostList and PageNo , want not mysql insert

Comment: You can't return `QuerySet` object (`queryset` in your code) from your view, you have to serialize them before returing

Answer (score 1):

Django Rest Framework has builtin pagination system. You don't have to manually create pagination. You can just `pagination_class` to your views to add pagination. Please read the documentation for more details.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/